# Writing title for a figure with calculated values NetworkX

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

This should be a trivial question. But I am confused. I want to print a value calculated by NetworkX in the title of a figure:

```
y=nx.average_clustering(G)
```

How should I correctly write the line:

```
plt.title('<C>='y)
```

where the title is a combination of words and values calculated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

String formatting is what you are working for.

```
plt.title('<C>={}'.format(y))
```

migh work for this example. You can also do the usual fixed width padding and such as described [in the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting). The `.format` form is the preferred way to do string formatting now as opposed to the `%` operator.